# Создание layout вне студии

Tags: android, android-studio

Всем привет. Вопрос, есть ли возможность создавать layout макеты вне студии? Интересует конкретно написание xml разметки. 
Может быть можно запустить стандартный редактор layout'ов вне студии?

Comment: То есть вы спрашиваете, можно ли редактировать xml вне студии?

Comment: вы можете писать разметку в любом текстовом редакторе, это обычный текстовый файл

Comment: @pavloff, не, это понятно, что текст можно в текстовых редакторах набирать, но есть ли возможность визуализировать набранную разметку?

Comment: нет, внешних (отдельных) визуальных редакторов разметки android , насколько я знаю, нет.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что можно использовать какой-нибудь продвинутый текстовый редактор, например, Sublime Text 2 с библиотекой Tag. ([статья на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/147856/)) Или [vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_as_XML_Editor).

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите создать layout в графическом виде, то нужно искать специально е ПО. Ну а в ином случае XML файл можно хоть в блокноте редактировать. Вопрос в том на сколько это удобно